# Javascript Calculation error

Tags: javascript

I made the following function to get the number of seconds from a time string.

```
function TimeStringToSeconds(TimeString){
    var TotalTime = 0;
    var SplitString = TimeString.toString().split(':');
    TotalTime += parseInt(SplitString[0])*3600;
    TotalTime += parseInt(SplitString[1])*60;
    TotalTime += parseInt(SplitString[2]);
    return TotalTime;
}
```

It works, but not if the input contains an 8 or an 9, example:

```
TimeStringToSeconds('00:01:00'); // Outputs 60
TimeStringToSeconds('00:02:00'); // Outputs 120
TimeStringToSeconds('00:08:00'); // Outputs 0   ???????
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always include the radix:

```
parseInt(SplitString[0], 10)
```

Without it, `"08"` is parsed in octal base, with `8` being an invalid digit.

See also: [parseInt at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a leading zero indicates octal notation. Use the following snippet:

```
parseInt(SplitString[0], 10)
```

This forces JavaScript to treat the number as decimal.